# get an ip automatic at direct connect

Tags: raspbian, dhcp, ethernet

I have a raspberry pi with raspbian and on the eth0 port it is connected to my network and gets an ip address via dhcp.

But now I want to unplug the ethernet cable and just use a new one that connects my pc directly to the pi.

Now my question is: Is it possible that the pi tells my pc an ip address to work with like an dhcp Server? So I dont need to do stuff in the adapter settings on my pc. Both sides should now have an ip address to communicate. Would it be possible that if I undo everything and connect the pi back to my network that the pi acts as dhcp client again?

Comment: You need to setup a DHCP server on your PC for this to work.

Comment: Doesnt it work the other way around? So the pi acts as server and the pc gets an ip?

Comment: Both are viable approaches. A server is by definition just a piece of software offering services.

Comment: My solution is now to let both the pi and the pc automaticly get a [zeroconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) ip and so they are in the same Network and can communicate.

Comment: if you care to elaborate a little you can answer your own question! :)

Answer (score 1):

After thinking that a dhcp server is a bit overkill for just to create a connection between two devices and also would couse problems if the Pi is connected again to a network witch already has a dhcp server I searched for other possibilities.

I found that, if a device cant reach a dhcp Server, the interface automaticly gets a [zeroconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) address after ~30 sek.

The zeroconf address has a range from 169.254.1.0/16 to 169.254.254.255/16.

So after connecting both devices and waiting a bit, both got an address and can now communicate.

Bonus: this also creates a kind of dns entry so I am able to ping my Pi (hostname raspberrypi) from my Windows pc with the address "raspberrypi.local".